# Cannot execute a rule over collection of objects

Tags: drools

I have set of rules which I want run over a collection of objects.

I have initiataed the statelesssession on rule base and then passed the Collection(i.e List) in execute method. it fires the those rules on any one of the object randomly. It ignores all other objects.

So how execute perticular set of rules on all objects in the List?

Comment: Please show you rule sample..

Answer (score 1):

You're going to give a few more details of your code and rules. I can recite the JavaDocs to you for StatelessKnowledgeSession's overloaded execute methods but that won't help. I looked at the source code, and provided everything else is OK, execute(Iterable) should do exactly what you want. Can you post your code and rules?